# Assign values to a void array?

Tags: c

Here's my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *create_array(int size) {
    double *v;

    v = (double*)malloc(size * sizeof(double));
    v[0] = (double)size;
    return (void*)v;

}

int main() {
    void *a;
    double b = 5;

    a = create_array(10);
    a[1] = b;

    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to assign the value stored in `b` to `(*a[1])`. I get the following error :

> "main.c:19:9: error: incomplete type 'void' is not assignable
> a[1]=b;"
> ~~~~^

Comment: Welcome to SO! What are you trying to do here? If you replace `void` with `double` you should be good to go. If you're trying to implement a "generic" array and/or some data structure that knows its own length, it's better to use a struct than sticking that info the first element, which results in some very unnatural and error-prone code.

Comment: `void *` exists mainly to tell the compiler that a pointer can be cast to any type implicitly. For example, `malloc()` returns a `void *` type, so you don't need to cast it to `(double *)` to assign it to `v`.  But there is no `void` variable type, that only indicates an expression (e.g. function) has no useful value. You can consider it to have a size of 0. That means you can't assign anything to it. You should never keep anything of type `void *` any longer than you have to, and if you can cast it to a useful type (`double *` in this case) you should always do that right away.

Comment: The tl;dr fix:  `((double*)a)[1] = b;`. This is safe because `a` actually points at a `double` array.

Answer (score 3):

### Main Answer

`void` is an incomplete type and cannot be used in expressions, including assignments. You can, however, have pointers to this type, `void *`. `void *` is a type that means “this points to something, but we are not saying what at this point.”

In order to use a `void *`, you must say what it points to, by converting it to a different kind of pointer, such as `double *`, which says “this points to a `double`.”

C, unlike C++, will do this conversion automatically in assignments. If we declare `a` with `double *a;` and then we assign it with `a = create_array(10);`, then the `void *` that is returned from `create_array` is automatically converted to a `double *` for storing in `a`. After that, we can write `a[1] = b;` to store `b` in the `double` at `a[1]`.

### Supplement

Your `create_array` contains a mix of `double *` and `void *`. It is better to either write a routine that is designed for a specific type:

```
double *create_array(int NumberOfElements)
{
    double *v = malloc(NumberOfElements * sizeof *v);
    v[0] = NumberOfElements; // (Yuck, this is ugly.)
    return v;
}
```

or to write a routine that handles any type:

```
void *create_array(int NumberOfElements, size_t SizeOfElement)
{
    void *v = malloc(NumberOfElements * SizeOfElement);
    // Cannot store size easily since we do not know what element type is.
    return v;
}
```

As noted, that business about storing the number of elements in the first element is messy. It is better to handle the size separately, even if that requires writing more code.

Also, avoid calling something just a “size,” because this can be confusing: Is the size of an array the number of elements in it or the number of bytes? The name or accompanying comments should always make the unit of measurement clear.

Answer (score 0):

neither pointers nor variables can be void type, just function's return

change to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
double *create_array(int size){
    double *v;

    v=(double*)malloc(size*sizeof(double));
    v[0]=(double)size;
    return (double*)v;

}
int main() {
    double *a;
    double b;
    b=5;

    a=create_array(10);
    a[1]=b;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't dereference a void *, but you can use a cast:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void *
create_array(int size)
{
        double *v = malloc(size * sizeof *v);
        if( v == NULL ){
                perror("malloc");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        v[0] = (double)size;
        return v;
}

int
main(void)
{
        void *a;
        double b = 5.0;
        double *c;

        c = a = create_array(10);
        ((double *)a)[1] = b;
        printf("%f  %f\n", c[0], c[1]);

        return 0;
}
```